# How to create new column with state region in R dataframe?

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that contains a column with state abbreviations ie. "IA", "IL", "IN,", etc. I would like to create a new column in my dataframe that assigns each row with the corresponding region ie. "Midwest", "Northeast," etc. Is there a package or good way to do this manually/with `mutate()` or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use inbuilt vectors to match and replace

```
df1$region <- setNames(state.region, state.abb)[df1$stateabb]
```

-output

```
> df1
  stateabb    region
1       AL     South
2       CO      West
3       CT Northeast
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(stateabb = c("AL", "CO", "CT")), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, R has two packages - state.abb has all the state abbreviations, state.region has their regions.
You don't need mutate, just cbind

Answer (score 0):

I work better using tidyverse language, so see this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mml05.png)for what I did for a similar task! It's more tedious but honestly didn't take long and is more digestible for me without having to look up new techniques. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please don't post code as an image, SO requires code to be added in codeblocks. Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).